# Field service lightning crashing on Android constantly

Tags: field-service-lightning

We have just implemented FSL in our business and all installers using FSL app on Android phones are reporting multiple crashes without exception. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a work around? Is sales force working on it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a know issue which hasn't yet fixed, but it only states *For Technicians who are using Salesforce Field Service Lightning Android Mobile app and trying to make a post with a file attachment other than image or video, the app crashes. 
The issue occurs with file types such as pdf/doc/csv/xml/txt/rtf etc. except for image (png, jpg, jpeg) and video (.mp4) files.*

**Reference:** [Salesforce Field Service Lightning Android Mobile - App crashes when trying to make a post with a file attachment other than image or video.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mD53QAE)

> **Workaround:** Use the FSL Android app to attach only image or video files till the issue gets fixed, and use the Salesforce mobile app or
>   browser based Full site to attach any other file types.

If your issue is not related to attachments and still experiencing this issue I would strongly suggest to raise a case with support.